# Question on pointwise convergence of a function

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ be given by 
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}n & x \in \left(0,\frac1n\right)\\
\frac1x & x \in \left[\frac1n,\infty\right) \end{cases}$$

I have to show that it would converge pointwise to $\frac1x$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Even though this seems to be an easy problem, but my concepts regarding this topic are a bit rusty, so it would be nice if someone could help me out !

I don't want the entire proof, just give me a headstart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x>0$ then there is a $n_0=n_0(x):\frac {1}{n_0}<x.$ If we take $n\geq n_0$ we have that $\frac {1}{n}<x$ and thus for every $n\geq n_0:f_n(x)=\frac {1}{x}\to \frac {1}{x}$ Thus $f_n(x)\to \frac {1}{x}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$\left.f_n\right|_{[\frac1n, \infty)} \equiv f$$
And since $\mathbb R^{+}$ is open, what can you say about a fixed point $x$?

Answer (score 0):

Fix some $x\in (0,\infty)$ and observe that $f_{n}(x)=1/x$ for $n$ large enough. This proves that there convergence in point $x$ to $f(x)=1/x$. This can be done for any  $x\in (0,\infty)$.